# Problema al instalar Netbeans 8.2 en Windows 10 Pro x64

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8.2, windows10

He intentado instalar *Netbeans 8.2* en mi equipo con *Windows 10 Pro x64.*
Anteriormente lo he instalado infinidad de veces y nunca me había topado con este problema hasta que formatie mi equipo e instale *Windows 10 pero con las últimas actualizaciones de Junio*.

Al ejecutar el instalador aparece la ventana de *configuring the installer* pero el problema es que después de terminar se cierran, y no aparece la siguiente ventana para seguir con la instalación, en lugar de eso aparece un registro con la siguiente información:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006ef96adf, pid=10912, tid=0x0000000000002214
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [msvcr100.dll+0x36adf]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000018bb8800):  JavaThread "Swing-Shell" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=8724, stack(0x000000001a330000,0x000000001a430000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000000

Registers: RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x000000001a42eb20, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x0000000000a4a3f0 RSP=0x000000001a42eac8, RBP=0x000000001a42ecd0, RSI=0x0000000000000021, RDI=0x0000000018bb89f8 R8 =0x0000000000a4a3f0, R9 =0x0000000000000000, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x000000001a42c180 R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x0000000019f769e0, R14=0x000000001a42ed10, R15=0x0000000018bb8800 RIP=0x000000006ef96adf, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000001a42eac8) 0x000000001a42eac8:   000000006e4e9d36 0000000000000000 0x000000001a42ead8:   0000000018bb89f8 0000000000000021 0x000000001a42eae8:   0000000000a4a3f0 0000000018bb89f8 0x000000001a42eaf8:   000000006e4ea6f9 0000000000a4a3f0 0x000000001a42eb08:   000000006e8d7895 0000000000000000 0x000000001a42eb18:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0x000000001a42eb28:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0x000000001a42eb38:   000000006e880553 0000000018afe290 0x000000001a42eb48:   0000000000000002 0000000018bb8800 0x000000001a42eb58:   00000000ffffffff 00000000ffffffff 0x000000001a42eb68:   000000006e95cb59 0000000018bb8800 0x000000001a42eb78:   0000000018ab5d00 0000000000000000 0x000000001a42eb88:   0000000000000538 00000000d9958000 0x000000001a42eb98:   0000000000000000 000000001a42ee00 0x000000001a42eba8:   0000000002c6bcf4 0000000018bb8800 0x000000001a42ebb8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000006ef96adf) 0x000000006ef96abf:   99 03 00 cc 33 c0 48 8b 5c 24 40 48 8b 74 24 48 0x000000006ef96acf:   48 83 c4 30 5f c3 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 48 8b c1 0x000000006ef96adf:   0f b7 10 48 83 c0 02 66 85 d2 75 f4 48 2b c1 48 0x000000006ef96aef:   d1 f8 48 ff c8 c3 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 45 33 c0 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value RBX=0x000000001a42eb20 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000018bb8800 RCX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value RDX=0x0000000000a4a3f0 is an unknown value RSP=0x000000001a42eac8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000018bb8800 RBP=0x000000001a42ecd0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000018bb8800 RSI=0x0000000000000021 is an unknown value RDI=0x0000000018bb89f8 is an unknown value R8
=0x0000000000a4a3f0 is an unknown value R9 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value R10=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value R11=0x000000001a42c180 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000018bb8800 R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value R13={method} {0x0000000019f769e8} 'getDisplayNameOf' '(JJI)Ljava/lang/String;' in 'sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2' R14=0x000000001a42ed10 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000018bb8800 R15=0x0000000018bb8800 is a thread


Stack: [0x000000001a330000,0x000000001a430000],  sp=0x000000001a42eac8,  free space=1018k Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code) C  [msvcr100.dll+0x36adf]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code) j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.getDisplayNameOf(JJI)Ljava/lang/String;+0 j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.access$1600(JJI)Ljava/lang/String;+4 j sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$13.call()Ljava/lang/String;+15 j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$13.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+1 j  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run()V+42 j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V+95 j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5 j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker$3.run()V+7 j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11 v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
=>0x0000000018bb8800 JavaThread "Swing-Shell" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=8724, stack(0x000000001a330000,0x000000001a430000)]   0x0000000018bae000 JavaThread "Image Fetcher 2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3308, stack(0x000000001a230000,0x000000001a330000)]   0x0000000018bad000 JavaThread "Image Fetcher 1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10224, stack(0x000000001a130000,0x000000001a230000)]   0x0000000018ba6000 JavaThread "Image Fetcher 0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6896, stack(0x0000000019e30000,0x0000000019f30000)]   0x0000000018ba5800 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=9400, stack(0x0000000019d30000,0x0000000019e30000)]   0x0000000018b18000 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=916, stack(0x0000000019620000,0x0000000019720000)]   0x0000000018b63000 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=7980, stack(0x0000000019520000,0x0000000019620000)]   0x0000000018b62800 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7916, stack(0x0000000019420000,0x0000000019520000)]   0x0000000016dbd800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8560, stack(0x0000000017f90000,0x0000000018090000)]   0x0000000016d9d000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10076, stack(0x0000000017e90000,0x0000000017f90000)]   0x0000000016d49800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6088, stack(0x0000000017d90000,0x0000000017e90000)]   0x0000000016d48000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9528, stack(0x0000000017c90000,0x0000000017d90000)]   0x0000000016d44800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4424, stack(0x0000000017b90000,0x0000000017c90000)]   0x0000000016d38800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8720, stack(0x0000000017980000,0x0000000017a80000)]   0x000000000287d800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7248, stack(0x0000000017880000,0x0000000017980000)]   0x0000000002790800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=2628, stack(0x00000000025c0000,0x00000000026c0000)]

Other Threads:   0x0000000016d16800 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000017780000,0x0000000017880000] [id=9836]   0x0000000016dc3800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000018090000,0x0000000018190000] [id=8320]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:  PSYoungGen      total 35840K, used 23641K [0x00000000d8400000, 0x00000000dac00000, 0x0000000100000000)   eden space 30720K, 76% used [0x00000000d8400000,0x00000000d9b165a0,0x00000000da200000)   from space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000da700000,0x00000000da700000,0x00000000dac00000)   to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000da200000,0x00000000da200000,0x00000000da700000)  ParOldGen  total 81920K, used 0K [0x0000000088c00000, 0x000000008dc00000, 0x00000000d8400000)   object space 81920K, 0% used [0x0000000088c00000,0x0000000088c00000,0x000000008dc00000)  Metaspace  used 17097K, capacity 17336K, committed 17664K, reserved 1064960K   class space    used 2124K, capacity 2199K, committed 2304K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000011c50000,0x0000000012010000] byte_map_base: 0x000000001180a000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000006eedc720  Begin Bits: [0x0000000012490000, 0x0000000014260000)  End Bits:   [0x0000000014260000, 0x0000000016030000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000910000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=4043Kb max_used=4043Kb free=241716Kb  bounds [0x0000000002890000, 0x0000000002c90000, 0x0000000011890000]  total_blobs=1645 nmethods=1130 adapters=429  compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events): Event: 2.421 Thread 0x0000000016d9d000 1127       3       java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject::await (98 bytes) Event: 2.422 Thread 0x0000000016d9d000 nmethod 1127 0x0000000002c81450 code [0x0000000002c81700, 0x0000000002c828e8] Event: 2.422 Thread 0x0000000016d9d000 1128       3       java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject::addConditionWaiter (64 bytes) Event: 2.423 Thread 0x0000000016d9d000 nmethod 1128 0x0000000002c830d0 code [0x0000000002c83260, 0x0000000002c83688] Event: 2.423 Thread 0x0000000016d9d000 1129       1       javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI::getFileChooser (5 bytes) Event: 2.423 Thread 0x0000000016d9d000 nmethod 1129 0x0000000002c83810 code [0x0000000002c83960, 0x0000000002c83a70] Event: 2.423 Thread 0x0000000016d9d000 1130       1       java.nio.DirectByteBuffer::isReadOnly (2 bytes) Event: 2.423 Thread 0x0000000016d9d000 nmethod 1130 0x0000000002c83ad0 code [0x0000000002c83c20, 0x0000000002c83d30] Event: 2.423 Thread 0x0000000016d9d000 1131       1       java.awt.MediaEntry::getID (5 bytes) Event: 2.423 Thread 0x0000000016d9d000 nmethod 1131 0x0000000002c83d90 code [0x0000000002c83ee0, 0x0000000002c83ff0]

GC Heap History (0 events): No events

Deoptimization events (8 events): Event: 1.800 Thread 0x0000000002790800 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002b14964 method=java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine()I @ 62 Event: 1.968 Thread 0x0000000002790800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002a34250 method=java.lang.String.startsWith(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z @ 25 Event:
2.079 Thread 0x0000000018ba5800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002b6ada8 method=java.util.HashMap.hash(Ljava/lang/Object;)I @ 1 Event: 2.239 Thread 0x0000000018ba5800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002a5dee8 method=java.lang.String.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 8 Event: 2.239 Thread 0x0000000018ba5800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002a5dee8 method=java.lang.String.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 8 Event: 2.239 Thread 0x0000000018ba5800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002a5dee8 method=java.lang.String.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 8 Event: 2.239 Thread 0x0000000018ba5800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002a5dee8 method=java.lang.String.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 8 Event: 2.377 Thread 0x0000000018ba5800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002c3e2f8 method=java.util.Hashtable.get(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 48

Internal exceptions (10 events): Event: 0.034 Thread 0x0000000002790800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.prefetchRead(Ljava/lang/Object;J)V name or signature does not match> (0x00000000d8407f90) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims Event: 0.137 Thread 0x0000000002790800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d856ba70) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390] Event: 0.137 Thread 0x0000000002790800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d856be68) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390] Event: 0.138 Thread 0x0000000002790800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d8570148) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390] Event: 0.138 Thread 0x0000000002790800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d8570540) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390] Event: 1.800 Thread 0x0000000002790800 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x00000000d95557d0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709] Event: 1.867 Thread 0x0000000002790800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x00000000d9621098) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1146] Event: 1.874 Thread 0x0000000002790800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x00000000d962e788) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1146] Event: 1.954 Thread 0x0000000002790800 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x00000000d97b06e8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709] Event: 2.079 Thread 0x0000000018ba5800 Implicit null exception at 0x0000000002b6ad2f to 0x0000000002b6ad99

Events (10 events): Event: 2.377 Thread 0x0000000018ba5800 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000002c3e2f8 sp=0x0000000019e2d390 Event: 2.377 Thread 0x0000000018ba5800 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x00000000028d582a sp=0x0000000019e2d348 mode 2 Event: 2.398 loading class sun/font/StandardGlyphVector Event: 2.398 loading class java/awt/font/GlyphVector Event: 2.398 loading class java/awt/font/GlyphVector done Event: 2.398 loading class sun/font/StandardGlyphVector done Event: 2.399 loading class sun/font/StandardGlyphVector$GlyphStrike Event: 2.399 loading class sun/font/StandardGlyphVector$GlyphStrike done Event: 2.399 loading class java/lang/StrictMath Event: 2.399 loading class java/lang/StrictMath done


Dynamic libraries: 0x00007ff661510000 - 0x00007ff661547000  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe 0x00007ffbb8410000 - 0x00007ffbb85eb000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll 0x00007ffbb7490000 - 0x00007ffbb753e000   C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL 0x00007ffbb5720000 - 0x00007ffbb5969000    C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll 0x00007ffbb2e60000 - 0x00007ffbb2ede000  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\apphelp.dll 0x00007ffbb5d50000
- 0x00007ffbb5df1000    C:\Windows\System32\ADVAPI32.dll 0x00007ffbb75d0000 - 0x00007ffbb766d000    C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll 0x00007ffbb7540000 - 0x00007ffbb7599000  C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll 0x00007ffbb79a0000
- 0x00007ffbb7ac5000    C:\Windows\System32\RPCRT4.dll 0x00007ffbb5970000 - 0x00007ffbb5aba000  C:\Windows\System32\USER32.dll 0x00007ffbb5480000 - 0x00007ffbb549e000  C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll 0x00007ffbb75a0000
- 0x00007ffbb75c7000    C:\Windows\System32\GDI32.dll 0x00007ffbb52f0000 - 0x00007ffbb5478000   C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll 0x00007ffbb4b50000 - 0x00007ffbb4bea000   C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll 0x00007ffbb54a0000 - 0x00007ffbb5596000   C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll 0x00007ffbaaf90000 - 0x00007ffbab1f7000    C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.15063.0_none_108e4f62dfe5d999\COMCTL32.dll 0x00007ffbb8080000 - 0x00007ffbb8379000   C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll 0x00007ffbb55a0000 - 0x00007ffbb560a000     C:\Windows\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll 0x00007ffbb5e00000 - 0x00007ffbb5e2d000    C:\Windows\System32\IMM32.DLL 0x000000006ef60000 - 0x000000006f032000   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll 0x000000006e6c0000 - 0x000000006ef5c000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll 0x00007ffbb5e30000 - 0x00007ffbb5e38000   C:\Windows\System32\PSAPI.DLL 0x00007ffbb28a0000 - 0x00007ffbb28c3000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll 0x00007ffbacb30000 - 0x00007ffbacb39000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll 0x00007ffbb7420000
- 0x00007ffbb748c000    C:\Windows\System32\WS2_32.dll 0x00007ffba1b70000 - 0x00007ffba1b7a000  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll 0x00007ffbb2840000 - 0x00007ffbb286b000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll 0x00007ffbb4930000 - 0x00007ffbb4979000   C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll 0x000000006e6b0000 - 0x000000006e6bf000    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\verify.dll 0x000000006e680000 - 0x000000006e6a9000   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\java.dll 0x000000006e660000 - 0x000000006e676000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\zip.dll 0x00007ffbb5fe0000 - 0x00007ffbb7417000  C:\Windows\System32\SHELL32.dll 0x00007ffbb7670000 - 0x00007ffbb771a000     C:\Windows\System32\shcore.dll 0x00007ffbb4bf0000
- 0x00007ffbb52e2000    C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll 0x00007ffbb5cf0000 - 0x00007ffbb5d41000     C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll 0x00007ffbb48c0000 - 0x00007ffbb48d1000     C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll 0x00007ffbb48e0000 - 0x00007ffbb492c000  C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll 0x00007ffbb4880000 - 0x00007ffbb4895000    C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll 0x00007ffbb42e0000
- 0x00007ffbb42f7000    C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll 0x00007ffbb3d50000 - 0x00007ffbb3d84000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll 0x00007ffbb4440000 - 0x00007ffbb4465000  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll 0x00007ffbb47b0000
- 0x00007ffbb47d9000    C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll 0x00007ffbb42d0000 - 0x00007ffbb42db000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll 0x000000006e640000 - 0x000000006e65a000   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\net.dll 0x00007ffbb4130000 - 0x00007ffbb418c000  C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll 0x00007ffbb3ed0000 - 0x00007ffbb3f07000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL 0x00007ffbb83e0000 - 0x00007ffbb83e8000    C:\Windows\System32\NSI.dll 0x00007ffbaa7d0000 - 0x00007ffbaa7e6000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL 0x00007ffbaa880000 - 0x00007ffbaa89a000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL 0x000000006e620000 - 0x000000006e631000    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\nio.dll 0x0000000000d60000 - 0x0000000000d67000  C:\Users\hl_he\AppData\Local\Temp\nbi-3103099072251605516.tmp 0x00007ffbb7720000 - 0x00007ffbb7865000   C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll 0x000000006e480000 - 0x000000006e618000   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\awt.dll 0x00007ffbb78e0000 - 0x00007ffbb79a0000  C:\Windows\System32\OLEAUT32.dll 0x00007ffbb2fe0000 - 0x00007ffbb3075000    C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll 0x00007ffbb7ad0000 - 0x00007ffbb7c36000     C:\Windows\System32\MSCTF.dll 0x00007ffbb27b0000 - 0x00007ffbb27da000   C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll 0x000000006e430000
- 0x000000006e477000    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\fontmanager.dll 0x00007ffb96a90000 - 0x00007ffb96b36000  C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.15063.413_none_0e0f5dcc67adff4e\comctl32.dll 0x00007ffbb5bd0000 - 0x00007ffbb5c6e000    C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll 0x00007ffbb22e0000 - 0x00007ffbb2476000     C:\Windows\system32\propsys.dll 0x00007ffb80670000
- 0x00007ffb80797000    C:\Windows\system32\NetworkExplorer.dll 0x00007ffbab450000 - 0x00007ffbab981000     C:\Windows\System32\OneCoreUAPCommonProxyStub.dll 0x00007ffbb1360000
- 0x00007ffbb150c000    C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WindowsCodecs.dll 0x00007ffb8b920000 - 0x00007ffb8b977000   C:\Windows\System32\thumbcache.dll 0x00007ffb861a0000 - 0x00007ffb862c1000  C:\Windows\system32\opengl32.dll 0x00007ffbaa170000 - 0x00007ffbaa19c000    C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\GLU32.dll 0x000000006e3e0000 - 0x000000006e422000   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\t2k.dll 0x00007ffba3f70000 - 0x00007ffba3f8b000  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MPR.dll 0x00007ffbb17d0000 - 0x00007ffbb17db000     C:\Windows\System32\drprov.dll 0x00007ffbb4330000
- 0x00007ffbb4385000    C:\Windows\System32\WINSTA.dll 0x00007ffba7a90000 - 0x00007ffba7aa6000  C:\Windows\System32\ntlanman.dll 0x00007ffba70f0000 - 0x00007ffba7110000    C:\Windows\System32\davclnt.dll 0x00007ffbb1790000
- 0x00007ffbb179c000    C:\Windows\System32\DAVHLPR.dll 0x00007ffbabee0000 - 0x00007ffbabef6000     C:\Windows\System32\wkscli.dll 0x00007ffba5380000 - 0x00007ffba5392000  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cscapi.dll 0x00007ffbb3fc0000
- 0x00007ffbb3fcd000    C:\Windows\System32\netutils.dll 0x00007ffb76340000 - 0x00007ffb7638a000    C:\Windows\System32\dlnashext.dll 0x00007ffba76d0000 - 0x00007ffba773d000   C:\Windows\System32\PlayToDevice.dll 0x00007ffba96c0000 - 0x00007ffba96de000    C:\Windows\System32\DevDispItemProvider.dll 0x00007ffba7fe0000 - 0x00007ffba8047000     C:\Windows\System32\MMDevApi.dll 0x00007ffbb3290000 - 0x00007ffbb32b8000    C:\Windows\System32\DEVOBJ.dll 0x00007ffb760f0000 - 0x00007ffb762cf000  C:\Windows\system32\wpdshext.dll 0x00007ffba2b90000 - 0x00007ffba2d25000    C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.15063.0_none_9055be80f37df5c1\gdiplus.dll 0x00007ffbb0020000 - 0x00007ffbb00bc000    C:\Windows\System32\PortableDeviceApi.dll 0x00007ffbb7c40000 - 0x00007ffbb807b000   C:\Windows\System32\SETUPAPI.dll 0x00007ffbb5610000 - 0x00007ffbb5666000    C:\Windows\System32\WINTRUST.dll 0x00007ffbb48a0000 - 0x00007ffbb48b1000    C:\Windows\System32\MSASN1.dll 0x00007ffbb4980000
- 0x00007ffbb4b49000    C:\Windows\System32\CRYPT32.dll 0x00007ffb89a10000 - 0x00007ffb89a46000     C:\Windows\System32\EhStorShell.dll 0x00007ffba70c0000 - 0x00007ffba70e5000     C:\Windows\System32\EhStorAPI.dll 0x00007ffbb2480000 - 0x00007ffbb2493000   C:\Windows\System32\WTSAPI32.dll 0x00007ffb89f70000 - 0x00007ffb89f80000    C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\LINKINFO.dll 0x00007ffba53a0000 - 0x00007ffba53ac000    C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\Secur32.dll 0x00007ffbb4780000 - 0x00007ffbb47b0000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SSPICLI.DLL 0x00007ffba1d90000
- 0x00007ffba1f39000    C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments: jvm_args:
-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\hl_he\AppData\Local\Temp\ -Dnetbeans.default_userdir_root=C:\Users\hl_he\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans
-Dnetbeans.default_cachedir_root=C:\Users\hl_he\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache java_command: org.netbeans.installer.Installer java_class_path (initial): C:\Users\hl_he\AppData\Local\Temp\\NBI01641.tmp\bundle.jar Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables: JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131 PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\hl_he\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Users\hl_he\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Bandizip\ USERNAME=hl_he OS=Windows_NT PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10.0 , 64 bit Build 15063 (10.0.15063.296)

CPU:total 2 (initial active 2) (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 58 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, clmul, erms, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

Memory: 4k page, physical 7812788k(4129480k free), swap 9713332k(5330836k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_131-b11), built on Mar 15 2017 01:23:53 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Mon Jul 03 15:52:47 2017 elapsed time: 2 seconds (0d 0h 0m 2s)
```

Comment: mira puedes arreglar los mensajes de error sinceramente es un abuso esperar que los aquí presentes lean este post... segundo si te da error de violación de acceso es por que no tienes los permisos para hacer la instalación o no estas ejecutando como administrado..

Comment: Borra ficheros de instalación, desistala Java JDK / JRE. Baja una versión de Netbeans que incluya Java e inicia la instalación como administrador.

Comment: Descargue el instalador de java con netbeans y lo ejecute como administrador, pero no pasa nada, sigue igual.

Comment: Se parece a una traza que me salía al actualizar el jdk a la verisón 1.8_131, resulta que mataba a netbeans cada que se trataba de abrir un archivo, esto debido a un error que ya se corrigió, más detalles en https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8179014